# Opera Top position rendering issue

Tags: html, css, position, opera

**HTML of the Page**
The issue is that the page is redering properly on mozilla,chrome and safari,
but on opera the is a space which is being inserted after the tabs and before the "mainright3" div which has all the content on the right side of the page..

Please help me out here..

Also if you know any tricks to make this work with i.e 9 please comment..

Its not compatible on i.e 9 now but any inputs on making it more friendly with ie9 will be great!(the page is not intended to support earlier ie's)

Thanks in Advance!!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Sakoota Back Office - Admin Management</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/admin-500.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/design.js"></script>
<!-- ImageReady Styles (admin page pro.ai) -->

<!-- Added for Developing Purpose -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/validate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/validate.css"/>
<!-- For Create and Edit menu tabs -->
</head>

<body>
<center>
<!-- TABLE_01 IS THE Main div containing the whole page -->

<!-- Table_01 Main Div covering the whole page-->
<div id="Table_01" style="font-family:customfont;">

<!-- FloatLog is the div containing "search box" "logout" and "Admin NAme"-->
<div id="floatlog">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['AdminLogin']; ?>!
    <a href="../logout.php?action=logout"  style="font-size:14px"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="../changePassword.php"  style="font-size:14px">Change password</a>
</div>

<div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png"></div><!--logo div--><!--top navigation bar : "top nav"--><!--blue navbar in the main navigation bar--><!--tabname is the manage label div--><!--tabname1 is the label of the current tba in the right content div-->

<span id="createMenu">  
<div id="topsecond"> <!--main tabs which are used to create and edit-->     
    <ul>
        <li id="grey"><a onClick="createPageView();">Create</a></li>
        <li id="blue"><a onClick="editPageView();" style="cursor:pointer;">Edit</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</span>
<span id="editMenu" style="display:none;">
<div id="topsecond"> <!--main tabs which are used to create and edit-->     
    <ul>
        <li id="blue"><a onClick="createPageView();" style="cursor:pointer;">Create</a></li>
        <li id="grey"><a onClick="editPageView();">Edit</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</span> 

<!-- Start for Manage Menu -->  
<div id="leftbarmain" class="greygradhor">
<div id="leftsec" class="bluegraddia">
    <?php include "../leftManageMenu.php"; ?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End for Manage Menu -->

<!-- Start for Body Right Menu--> 
<div id="mainright">
<div id="labeltablelist" class="greygradhor" style="text-align:justify"></div>

<span id="acknowledgeMsgBoard" style="text-align:center; color:#fff;"></span>



<!-- Start for Create Page --> 
<span id="createPageView">
<form  name="log" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="hdAction" id="hdAction"> 
<div id="righhidable">
<div id="mainsec" class="bluegraddia">
<div id="labeltablelist1" class="greygradhor" style="text-align:justify"><div id="tablelabels1"></div></div>
<div id="formn">

<!-- Success Message for Created User Start -->  
    <span id="successMsg" style="margin-left:200px;"></span>
<!-- Success Message for Created User End -->  

    <div id="leftaligntext">
    <div style=" padding-top:10px;">
    <div style="font-family:customfont;font-size:16px;color:#FFF">Full Name<span style="color:#900;">*</span></div>
    <input type="text" class="textfield tfont" id="name" name="name" value="" style="width:200px; padding:3px; padding-left:10px;" ><br>
    </div>
    <span id="nameErrMsg" ></span>

    <br><div style="font-family:customfont;font-size:16px;color:#FFF">Login Name<span style="color:#900;">*</span></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="textfield tfont" id="loginname" name="loginname" value="" onBlur="checkName();" style="width:200px; padding:3px; padding-left:10px"><br></div>
    <span id="loginnameErrMsg" ></span>

    <br><div style="font-family:customfont;font-size:16px;color:#FFF">Email ID<span style="color:#900;">*</span></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="textfield tfont" id="email" name="email" value="" onBlur="checkEmail();" style="width:200px; padding:3px; padding-left:10px"><br></div>
    <span id="emailErrMsg" ></span>

    <br><div style="font-family:customfont;font-size:16px;color:#FFF">Confirm Email ID<span style="color:#900;">*</span></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="textfield tfont" id="cemail" name="cemail" value="" style="width:200px; padding:3px; padding-left:10px"><br></div>
    <span id="cemailErrMsg" ></span>

    <br><div style="font-family:customfont;font-size:16px;color:#FFF">Phone</div>
    <div><input type="text" class="textfield tfont" id="phone" name="phone" value="" style="width:200px; padding:3px; padding-left:10px"><br></div>
    <span id="phoneErrMsg" ></span>
    </div>

    <div id="rightaligntextad">
    <br><span style="color:#900; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; margin-right:10px;">* Fields are mandatory...</span>

    <br><div style="font-family:customfont; font-size:16px; color:#FFF; padding-left:22px; text-align:left">Mobile<span style="color:#900;">*</span></div>
    <input type="text" class="textfield tfont" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" style="width:200px; padding:3px; padding-left:10px"><br>
    <span id="mobileErrMsg" style="float:left; margin-left:20px"></span>

    <br><div style="font-family:customfont; font-size:16px; color:#FFF; padding-left:22px; text-align:left">Location<span style="color:#900;">*</span></div>
    <input type="text" class="textfield tfont" id="location" name="location" value="" style="width:200px; padding:3px; padding-left:10px"><br>
    <span id="locationErrMsg" style="float:left; margin-left:20px"></span><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content" style="text-align:left;" class="greygradhor"><span id="accessErrMsg"  style="text-align:center;width:200px;margin-left:205px;"></span>
    <!--End For Message Display-->

    <div id="lastbuttons" style="text-align:right">
      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="bluegraddialabel"  style="cursor:pointer; height:47px;">
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="RESET" class="bluegraddialabelReset"  style=" cursor:pointer; height:47px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</span>
<!-- End for Create Page --> 

</div>
<!-- End for Body Right Menu-->   

  </div>
</div>


<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** please ignore unwanted code in the form of any script content in html or extra classes in css..

```
 @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */



#Table_01 {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:1024px;
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom:300px;
}

#formn{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
}
#topnav {
    position:absolute;
    left:280px;
    top:44px;
    width:744px;
    height:65px;
}
.greygradhor{
    background: #ededed; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%, #cecece 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ededed), color-stop(100%,#cecece)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#cecece',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    font-family:customfont;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#666;
}

#navbar {
    margin-top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:56px;
    width:704px;
    height:33px;
    left: 299px;
}
.bluegradhor{
    background: #4acbef; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #4acbef 0%, #00a3de 51%, #008cc7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#4acbef), color-stop(51%,#00a3de), color-stop(100%,#008cc7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(left,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4acbef', endColorstr='#008cc7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
}

#tabname {
}

#mainsec {
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 10px 10px;
    padding-top:48px;
    height:auto;
    background: #4acbef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%, #00a3de 51%, #008cc7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#4acbef), color-stop(51%,#00a3de), color-stop(100%,#008cc7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* W3C */


filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4acbef', endColorstr='#008cc7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
}

#leftbarmain {
    position:absolute;
    left:16px;
    top:100px;
    width:243px;
    height:601px;
}
#leftsec {
    position:absolute;
    left:6px;
    top:8px;
    width:231px;
    height:579px;
    z-index:1;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.bluegraddia{
    background: #4acbef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%, #00a3de 51%, #008cc7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#4acbef), color-stop(51%,#00a3de), color-stop(100%,#008cc7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4acbef', endColorstr='#008cc7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;

}
.bluegraddialabel{
    background: #29ABE2;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.bluegraddialabel1{
    background: #29ABE2;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.bluegraddialabelReset{
    background: #29ABE2;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    padding-top:10px;
}

#mainright {
    position:relative;
    left:145px;
    top:100px;
    width:740px;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding-top:0px;
}

#mainright3 {
    position:relative;
    left:145px;
    top:191px;
    width:740px;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding-top:0px;
}

#topsecond {
    position:absolute;
    left:311px;
    top:41px;
    width:410px;
    height:47px;
}

#topsecond ul li#blue{
    color:#ffff;
    background: #007ead;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0095cc', endColorstr='#00678e');
}

#topsecond ul li#gray{
    color:#06F;
    background: #ededed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#dcdcdc));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #dcdcdc);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dcdcdc');
}
0
body{
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}


#topsecond > ul{
    font-size: 1em;
    list-style:none;
}

#topsecond ul li{
    margin:0 25px 0 0;
    padding:10px 35px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    background: #ededed; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%, #cecece 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ededed), color-stop(100%,#cecece)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #ededed 0%,#cecece 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#cecece',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
}



a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:customfont;
    color:#29abe1;
    font-size:26px;
}
.buttons {
    margin-top:25px;
    z-index:1000;
    float:left;
    height:36px;
    width:230px;
    margin-left:-8px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#tabname{
    position:absolute;
    left:288px;
    top:133px;
    width:163px;
    height:58px;
    background: #4acbef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%, #00a3de 51%, #008cc7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#4acbef), color-stop(51%,#00a3de), color-stop(100%,#008cc7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4acbef', endColorstr='#008cc7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    padding-top:15px;
}
#tabname1{
    position:absolute;
    left:53px;
    top:134px;
    width:162px;
    height:54px;
    background: #4acbef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%, #00a3de 51%, #008cc7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#4acbef), color-stop(51%,#00a3de), color-stop(100%,#008cc7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  #4acbef 0%,#00a3de 51%,#008cc7 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4acbef', endColorstr='#008cc7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.tabname{
     font-family:customfont;
     color:#FFF; 
     font-size:26px
}
.textfield{
    font-family:customfont;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top:25px;
    height:25px;
    color:#333;
}
#textfield1{
    font-family:customfont;
    padding-top:25px;
    height:25px;
    color:#333;
}

#leftaligntext{
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    width:320px;

}
#leftaligntext2{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    width:320px;

}
#rightaligntext{margin:0;padding:0}

#rightaligntext1{
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    width:284px;
    height: 293px;
    left: 14px;
    bottom:400px;
}
#rightaligntextad{
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    width:224px;
    height: 217px;
    left: 490px;
    top: -9px;
}
#rightaligntextsub{
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    width:359px;
    height: 324px;
    left: 355px;
    top: -9px;

}
#rightaligntextsub1{
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    width:359px;
    height: 348px;
    left: 355px;
    top: -9px;

}
#content{
    left: 8px;
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    padding:30px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#labelbuttoncontent{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:40px;
    width:244px;
    height:42px;
    font-family:customfont;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#FFF;
}


#submit{
    width:110px;
    height:38px;
    font-family:customfont;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#FFF;
}
#reset{
    position:relative;
    width:110px;
    height:38px;
    font-family:customfont;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#FFF;
}
.dropshadow{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
}
.logo{
    position:absolute;
    left: 14px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 143px;
    height: 107px;
}
input.largerCheckbox
{
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
#labelcontent{
    margin-left:-400px;
    width: 257px;
}
#labelcontent2{
    margin-top:-27px;
    margin-left:400px;
    width: 257px;
}
#labeltablelist{
    position:absolute;
    left: 1px;
    width: 763px;
    height: 45px;
    top: -1px;
    text-align:justify;
    }
#labeltablelist1{
    position:absolute;
    left: -12px;
    width: 764px;
    height: 45px;
    top: -1px;
    text-align:justify;
    }
#tablelabels{
    position:relative;
    left: 14px;
    top: 6px;
    width: 673px;
    color:#29abe1;
    height: 45px;
}
#tablelabels1{
    position:absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 744px;
    height:36px;
    color:#29abe1;
}

#floatlog{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 43px;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-top:58px;
}

#leftaligntext1{
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    width:227px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 29px;
    height: 181px;
}
.radiobutton{
    color:#ffff;
    position:relative;
    left: -1px;
    top: 16px;
    width: 239px;
}

#topsecond ul li{
    /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

#topsecond ul li#blue:hover {
    background: #ededed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#dcdcdc));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #dcdcdc);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dcdcdc');
}

#topsecond ul li:active {
    color: #80bed6;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0078a5), to(#00adee));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0078a5,  #00adee);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0078a5', endColorstr='#00adee');
}
#righhidable{
    position:relative;
}
.tfont{
    font-family:customfont;
    font-size:16px;
}
#search{
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-radius:6px;
}





#leftaligntext2sub{
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    width:320px;

}
```

Comment: I SOLVED it---I removed the position value top and used clear above the "mainright3" div.. as opera doesnt display the div properly with top value-100

Comment: Now that browsers are using their HTML5 parsers, all your HTML errors should be rendered the same among those using the HTML5 parser. Older versions (and IE9), however, will still be using their old error-rendering which will be different. For example, inline spans can't wrap block divs.

Comment: @aravind If you solved your problem - close the question please.

Answer (score 0):

hai i fix the  opera browsers issues, the technique is follows.

1) first thing  remove  #mainright3,  because  #mainright and #mainright3 styles are both.
2) you do the small adjustments in  #mainright  it as follows ,now  easily working in opera browsers.

```
#mainright {
position:relative;
width:740px;
height:auto;
padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
margin:0px;
float:right;
```

}